# Solr demote all documents with condition

Tags: solr, edismax, solr-query-syntax, solr-boost

I want to demote all documents that have inv=0(possible values from 0 to 1000) to the end of the result set. i have got other sorting options like name desc also as part of the query.

For example below are my solr documents

```
Doc1 : name=apple , Inv=2
Doc2 : name=ball , Inv=1
Doc3 : name=cat , Inv=0
Doc4 : name=dog , Inv=0
Doc5 : name=fish , Inv=4
Doc6 : name=Goat , Inv=5
```

I want achieve below sorting ...here, i want to push all documents with inv=0 down to bottom and then apply "name asc" sorting.

```
Doc1
Doc2
Doc5
Doc6
Doc3
Doc4
```

my solr request is like

> bq: "(*:* AND -inv:"0")^999.0" & defType: "edismax"

here 999 is the rank that i gave to demote results.

this boosting query works fine. it moves all documents with inv=0 down to the bottom.

But when i add &sort=name asc to the solr query, it prioritizes "sort" over bq..i am seeing below results with "name asc".

```
Doc1 : name=apple , Inv=2
Doc2 : name=ball , Inv=1
Doc3 : name=cat , Inv=0
Doc4 : name=dog , Inv=0
Doc5 : name=fish , Inv=4
Doc6 : name=Goat , Inv=5
```

can anyone please help me out. ?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution: You can just sort by `inv` first, then the other values. This requires that `inv` only have true (1) or false (0) values. I guess that is not the case, so:

You can sort by a function query - and you can use the function `if` to return different values based on whether the value is set or not:

```
sort=if(inv, 1, 0) desc, name desc
```

If Solr fails to resolve `inv` by itself, you can use `field(inv)`, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Another option is to use the function `min` to get either 1 or 0 for the sort field, depending on whether it's in inventory or not:

```
sort=min(1, inv)
```

Comment: Thanks. But i dont want to sort by inv (inventory  can have values from 0 to 1000). i just want to sort by name but have all records that have value 0 at the end .is the map function usable here. how can i use it

Comment: "Having all the records that have value 0 at the end" is by default sorting. By using the `if` function query as illustrated (or the min version), the only values will be either 0 or 1 for sorting. The next sort field will then give the direction within that sort again. Please give an example if this does not give the correct result as you expect. Using map should not be necessary (but would be possible), but you'd still have to sort by the value to get the documents to come last.

Comment: Hi, I tried &sort=min(1, field(inv)) desc, name_ntk desc it did not work.

Comment: I tried below 1.sort=name desc, if(exists(query({!v='inv:0'})), 1, 0) desc  also

Comment: for some reason , when i press enter, comment closes and i can't edit the comment here on stackoverflow. Ok ..sorry about that. i also tried sort=if(inv, 1, 0) desc, name desc     also tried   &sort=map(inv,0,0,inv,0),name desc   ...nothing seems to work. i am new to solr terminology. could you give me the entire sort query string please ?